# Parwan assembler code to add a list of numbers

Tags: assembly, numbers

I'm trying to write a short bit of assembly code to run through a parwan processor test bench. The assembler program should use a loop to add the following numbers: 8,6,4,19,24,7,2,12,1,3,9 and store the result in memory at an arbitrary memory location.

I don't have much experience with assembly, this is 1993 syntax I believe.

```
         --load 25 in 4:00
         --load 10 in 4:01
         --load 01 in 4:02

0:15 cla --clear accumulator
0:16 asl --clears carry
0:17 add , i 4:00 --add bytes
0:19 sta 4:03 --store partial sum
0:1B lda 4:00 --load pointer
0:1D add 4:02 --increment pointer
0:1F sta 4:00 --store pointer back
0:21 lda 4:01 --load count
0:23 sub 4:02 --decrement count
0:25 bra_z :2D --end if zero count
0:27 sta 4:01 --store count back
0:29 lda 4:03 --get partial sum
0:2B jmp 0:17 --go for next byte
0:2D nop --adding completed
```

I have found this as an example to go off but I'm not sure how to implement it. How do I code the numbers to be loaded at certain memory locations, as I would want say --load 8 in 4:00 and do that for all the numbers in my list? Then the rest of the code would more or less satisfy the task albeit maybe with a few additional lines?

Comment: Copy/pasting code from the Internet seldom works out well.  Work through the logic, and write some code yourself, instead of trying to modify someone's code that you already don't understand.

Comment: You're right. However the instruction set available doesn't include a function for loading values into the memory, just the accumulator? or would I need to load the values separately then store them, before I begin my main code? Used to using C

Comment: Is this x86 assembly?  Look up the `mov` instruction.

Comment: No it is to code a very simple VHDL description of a 16-bit parwan processor. Only seemingly 17 instructions available, load accumulator, add sub jump branch clear etc. Pretty basic just don't know the standard format for some of the things.

Comment: Can you point me to a spec sheet, opcode specification or something similar?

Comment: [link](http://www.eecstc.yuntech.edu.tw/yuntecheec/program/ics/htsc/eng_pag/download/verilog/Parn1_cpumodel.pdf)

Comment: The first 4 or 5 pages of that

Comment: The LDA and STA instructions accomplish what you want.

Comment: So I would use LDA to load the values, give them an address to store STA, for each of the values in the list. Then have the pointer decrement or increment between the addresses, storing the cumulative value at a different location and adding each number in the list to that address, then storing it again? Like C could I just define them like variables at the start or do I have to load and store then clear before creating the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORG     00:0000
CLA         --clear accumulator
ASL         --clears carry
ADD,I   00:0020 --adds value of memory location 0020 to ac
STA     00:0040 --store ac value in 0040
LDA     00:0020 --load pointer from memory loc 20
ADD,M   00:0001
STA     00:0020
LDA     00:0021
SUB,M   00:0001
BRA_Z   00:0018
STA     00:0021
LDA     00:0040
JMP     00:0002
LDA     00:0040
STA     00:0040
NOP     
JMP     00:001C


ORG     00:0020
VALUE   00:0030--pointer for memory address
VALUE   00:000A--number of iterations of loop


ORG     00:0030
VALUE   00:000D-data values in hex
VALUE   00:0008
VALUE   00:0006
VALUE   00:0005
VALUE   00:0013
VALUE   00:0015
VALUE   00:0007
VALUE   00:0001
VALUE   00:000C
VALUE   00:0003
```

This is the base of what you should be working off to achieve this.

http://www.ohio.edu/people/starzykj/network/Class/ee514/parwan.pdf

This link includes the instruction set.

Ps. obviously those values are different.